# openstack selfservice network setup

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, vxlan

I'm trying to configure the selfservice network on Openstack Wallaby, running on Ubuntu Server 20.04.  I have followed the instructions for everything under the "Minimal deployment for Wallaby" section under "Install OpenStack services" on the docs.openstack.org site, and all services are running.  I followed "Networking Option 2" when setting up Neutron.

For the physical network, I have a dedicated subnet, 10.93.10.0/24, on our campus network, with a gateway at 10.93.10.1.  en1 and en2 are both connected to this network, with en1 being used for Openstack management.  The controller node is at 10.93.10.10, and I have a compute node at 10.93.10.21.  en2 is up on both nodes, but does not have an IP address assigned.

Now, following the instructions under "Launch an instance", I created the provider network, and the selfservice network and subnet, then created a router to connect the selfservice network to the provider network.  This all *seems* to work, but the output of the 'ip netns' command only shows the qrouter line.  The docs say that I should also see 2 qdhcp lines.  Also, the output of 'openstack port list --router router' shows the status of both ports as 'Down'.

Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It is possible to deactivate DHCP in the subnet. If you did that, no DHCP namespace will be created. Otherwise, troubleshooting starts with `openstack network agent list` (any agents down?) and a search for WARNINGs and ERRORs in the Neutron log files.

Comment: 'openstack network agent list' shows that metadata agent, DHCP agent, and L3 agent are all up.  I'll go thru the logs and see what's there.